# Sequence containing infinite prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let’s us take an infinite set of positive integer numbers defined with certain relation $\{ a,b,...\}$. Iif we can prove it contains infinitely many numbers of the form $a+nd$, where $a,d$ are coprime, then will it be okay to say it contains infinitely many prime numbers as stated by Dirichlet's theoremm?

Comment: No.  The sequence $\{2+2md\}_{m=0}^{\infty}$ only contains $1$ prime, even if $d$ is odd.

Comment: Here if we compare your relation to a+nd then we will get a=2 and d=2d .so a and d are not coprime .My question if for the case where a and d are coprime as stated by dirichlet theorem

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Take $d=1$ in my sequence.

Comment: If you want another example, start with the sequence $\{4k+1\}$, so $a=4$, $d=1$.  That contains infinitely many primes, of course, but it also contains infinitely many non-primes (easily proven).  Let $S$ be the subsequence of all the non-primes in that progression.

Comment: Yeah next one makes sense .And i also asked just because of that.Thanks for your argument.

Answer (score 1):

To see that this is false, start with the sequence $\{4k+1\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$, so $a=4, d=1$ in your notation.    By Dirichlet, that contains infinitely many primes.

Of course, it also contains infinitely many non primes:

(Pf:  say $p=4k+1$ is prime.  Then $p\,|\,(4(k+np)+1)$  $\;\;\forall n$.)

Let $S$ be the sequence of all non-primes congruent to $1 \pmod 4$.  $S$ is a counterexample to your desired claim.

A similar argument works for every arithmetic progression.